# IIS 6 - 'share located on another computer' greyed out

Tags: clickonce, iis-6, windows-server-2003, unc, virtual-directory

As part of our migration off of a Windows Server 2003 machine which is hosting a legacy ClickOnce application, we need to move the ClickOnce app to a newer server (2012 R2). To verify it will work without interruption, we need to execute the ClickOnce app while its codebase and app update URL have been moved to the 2012 server.

To achieve this we intended to set the properties of the ClickOnce app in IIS 6 to get its content from 'a share located on another computer'. However, this option is greyed out and not selectable - for this or any subdirectory of any website on this 2003 server. How can we enable this option in IIS?

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone needs the answer to this, we figured it out. What must be done is to remove the Application in IIS 6 by right-clicking the virtual directory where the gear icon is, and selecting Remove Application. Next, choose Create Application on the target virtual directory. The dialog shown will have a working 'share located on another computer' entry field.